# using a variable name within dataframe name

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes namely `a_df` and `b_df` and have defined them separately under two different if conditions.

Once, outside the conditions I want to use them like `{i}_df['col']` where the value is input by user and can be a, or b. How do I incorporate a variable into the name of dataframe as such.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the a valuable solution in this case is to use a dictionary for mapping the user input with the actual dataframe. For example:

```
my_dict={'a':a_df,'b':b_df}
```

Then, you select the correct element according to the provided input. Something like the following:

```
user_input=input('Your choice: ')

try:
    print(my_dict[user_input])
except:
    print("Not valid!")
```

Hope it helps!